# How can we add a paper size to printer programmatically

Tags: windows, printing

In windows, how can a program add a custom paper size to a specific printer?
To be more specific, we want this change to be permanently visible outside that program, so that other programs can print to that paper size.

We have been able to do that by importing registry values from a file, but that requires admin access, which makes it troublesome in the company.

A solution in any language/stack will be appreciated.

Comment: Changing default printer setting may require admin rights. Does [Set-PrinterConfiguration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/printmanagement/set-printconfiguration) cmdlet fit your task?  Example: **Set-PrintConfiguration -PrinterName "Microsoft Print to PDF" -PaperSize "A3"**

Comment: As I understand you have to work with registry hive "HKLM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Print\Forms". Print form application must have administrative rights to change this hive. Otherwise app must have interface to work with service changing registry values. So you have to write application and service for enterprise computer. Service can be group policy spreading predefined print forms values over enterprise (AD) domain.

Answer (score 0):

With Set-PrintConfiguration only can set predefine paper, cannot add custom paper size